# Am I ruining my laptop battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, charger

I have a brand new Asus ux303ln.

The laptop is fine but I use it mostly for work. That is: le laptop is continuosly plugged in, on charge. I am worried whether this can reduce the life of my battery (like for the old laptops I used to work with ten years ago). Is it still the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leaving laptop plugged in all the time](http://superuser.com/questions/108993/leaving-laptop-plugged-in-all-the-time), [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Comment: Check your options (generally vendor-supplied config options) to see if there's an option to only charge to 60-80%.  If there is such an option, enable it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the battery technology involved in this question is very different from the battery technology in the supposed duplicate question. Correct answers to the two questions would be *very* different. (And it's still different yet again today. And there is no accurate answer to this question for modern laptops on this site, at least not that I could find.)