# Battery on or off while running the laptop on electricity?

Tags: battery, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

I have an HPcompaq nc6400 but I don't have much information about batteries.when I'm home I run it on electricity so at this time should I take the battery out or it's OK if I run it on electricity with battery on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's okay for short periods of time. (e.g charging it back up while running.) However, the heat a laptop generates adversely affects lithium ion battery chemistry and causes it to lose capacity (as it does naturally) at a significantly quicker rate.

So, for the longest possible battery life, you will want to remove your laptop battery when working on AC for long periods of time.

Comment: It's happened to me once or twice while running on AC the electricity has gone out,so the laptop turned off with isn't it harmful for computer in this case?

Comment: It can be, if you're working on an unsaved file and the power goes out. Generally, your biggest risk is losing unsaved data. Damage to your hardware is unlikely. If you want the laptop battery to last as long as possible, I would suggest you consider purchasing an Uninterruptable Power Supply (UPS), which uses big, heavy lead-acid batteries that last forever to provide AC power. If that's not an option, you certainly can leave your laptop battery in all the time, but it could shorten the useful life of it quite a bit.

Comment: I guess you're right bro.thanks for the informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the battery in.  It'll recharge while plugged in bypass the battery once fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

The battery will charge as needed and the system will not draw off of it when it is plugged in, appreciably.

Leave the battery plugged in., it won't hurt anything.

(edit: grammar)

Comment: There is an edit summary field when you edit, that's where you put in the edit note.