# Laptop operating suggestion

Tags: windows, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Should i use my Laptop on battery or direct on electricity. i have no problem of electricity and i use my laptop in home and no problem of getting it with me outside.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for programming questions, so your question about laptop battery is off topic. The associated site http://superuser.com would be better for this question.

Comment: If you want your battery to go dead, you should avoid plugging your laptop into the wall.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged) and [Battery on or off while running the laptop on electricity?](http://superuser.com/questions/136397/battery-on-or-off-while-running-the-laptop-on-electricity).

Comment: the suggestions of removing a fully charged battery to prevent it from receiving excess heat (in the links above) are all well and good, but doing that mitigates the advantage of having a built in UPS.

Answer (score 2):

If you have electricity available, you obviously want to use that. Your battery has a limited number of recharging cycles and should be used only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pekka's reply, a comment:

When the laptop is not on mains power, it may enter power-saving mode, which will degrade the quality of the display or other components. For better user experience, use mains power.