# Proper way to charge laptop

Tags: battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

I want to expand the lifetime of my battery which is a 6-cell lithium ion. I've read somewhere for Li-Ion cell phones that we should let the battery die before charging it. Is that the same with my laptop? My laptop is always plugged in. Should I not use it plugged in and keep on using it on battery and charge when low?

Answer (score 2):

Lion batteries can be damaged by draining them completely before recharge, that method is for old Nicad/Nmhi batteries.

Some suggestions here

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&tmp_track_link=ot_recdoc/c00817650/en_us/c01297640/loc:4&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4125509

Lion technology article here

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4125509&docname=c00596784