# Is working plugged-in bad for laptop battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Some sources (even here on SuperUser) state that working plugged-in kills the laptop's battery because of micro-recharges. And that it is good to remove battery from a laptop, when working plugged-in. Some state exactly the opposite. So:

- Is this true or not? Should you remove the battery or not?
- Some say that it's true - but for old NiMH batteries **only**, is that
  correct?
- How about modern laptops with non-removable batteries? (e.g.
  MacBook 2011)