# Leaving the charger in the laptop after it is fully charged

Tags: power-management, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Is there any problem if I left the charger connected to the laptop after full charging?
And if there is, How can I deal with that to not harm the battery?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: May be suited for SuperUser, but not SO...

Comment: This is off topic, but [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/do_and_dont_battery_table) is some information for you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/12838/108226 and a bunch of others.

Comment: Yeah, there are at least a couple of duplicates, but no single one addresses all the issues, that I can see.

Comment: Minor gripe:  When a thread is closed for being a "dupe" they say that some answers should be moved from the dupe to the "original".  But I've never seen that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laptop chargers pretty much universally turn off (or go into low "trickle" mode) when the battery is fully charged.

There is a problem, however, that your typical Li-ion laptop battery "doesn't like" being fully charged -- the overall battery life (not the "life" of a single charge) will be extended if only charged to 60-80%.  Some laptops have a setting to enable this lower-level charge (for those that hardly ever use the laptop on battery only), but many unfortunately do not.

Answer (score -1):

Read the topics in this site: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/do_and_dont_battery_table

Usually the battery stop charging after completion. So normally you can leave it. Actually, I think the charge/discharge process is what decrease the batteries performance.

You have more info [here](http://askville.amazon.com/harm-leaving-rechargeable-batteries-plugged-long-periods-time-remote-control-toys/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=7344787)

Hope it helps.

Comment: and http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MA348LL/A?pqid=QCAK47PCKDXHYAAHF9T9Y7ADC92DATUJD