# Is there a way to tell a laptop not to use the battery, besides removing it?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

Is there a way to tell a laptop not to use the battery, besides removing the battery physically? I mostly use the laptop as a desktop, but sometimes may need to take it into anothewr room.

Comment: To my knowledge, the laptop, when it knows it is fully charged, it won't use the battery and use simply the AC power connected. Once the AC power removed, then the battery kicks in.

Comment: @Darius why then battery still remains hot?

Comment: All I can say is because the battery is still receiving power from the laptop. But if the laptop somehow noticed the battery is draining (for whatever reason) then it will put some more charge to it. Based on some answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/722175/run-laptop-off-ac-power-without-charging-battery?rq=1) there is a mention (depends on the laptop) that some laptops can allow non-charging even when plugged in (Dell QuickSet is mentioned and the method [here](http://superuser.com/questions/722175/run-laptop-off-ac-power-without-charging-battery?rq=1)) So it may be laptop dependant