# Charging Android phone battery

Tags: android, battery, smartphone

I usually connect my Android phone to my laptop with USB and leave it even after fully charged. Is it OK or harmful ? Will it reduce my battery lifetime ?

Comment: This is barely on-topic for SU IMO.  to that end, the suggested duplicate is about laptops, but (most of) the answers apply in general to any rechargeable device, not just laptops.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Answer (score 1):

> When your phone is completely charged, it switches to a trickle effect. This means that it'll draw only as much power from its power adapter as it needs to keep its full charge. Your phone still expends energy as long as it's on, even if it's plugged in. Whenever the battery is fully charged, however, it simply stops charging and will suffer no ill effects. Your battery will probably degrade from the effects of time before it experiences any issues from charging overnight.

So in turn, you are fine to keep it plugged in, even after it's charged, I always unplug mine personally just to be safe, but that's just me.

[Source](http://classroom.synonym.com/smartphone-charger-stop-after-its-full-17317.html)

Comment: Thanks. But why you unplug yours just TO BE SAFE?

Comment: Because I am of the mindset that "just because it's supposed to do "x" doesn't mean it always will."  So yes, you have pry a 95% chance of everything being ok leaving it plugged in, very very small chance anything will go wrong, but it COULD, and to me, I'd just assume avoid that 5%, granted I leave mine plugged in all night when I sleep, so I don't always follow these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it plugged in is always better as the battery life depreciates more rapidly when you use the phone unplugged. Also, never let you battery run out or get low. It is always better to charge it whenever possible in order to maintain a longer healthier charge and life. This is opposite of what we 
have been told in the past in older batteries for example in laptops during the turn of the century where it was better to let you battery fully drain as to keep the timing mechanism in check however again this is not the case in the newer lithium batteries and it is always better to charge whenever and whenever you can. go here for more info: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries