# Macbook Pro Battery Life: Battery vs. Power Adapter

Tags: battery-life, macbook-pro-retina

What is better for my Macbook's Pro 13' 2015 battery life:
1) Loading it to 100% and then using it to ~20%, loading it again
OR
2) Using it plugged in to the power adapter all the time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using your battery at least a few times a week, and recharging it afterward, even if it is only for a short time.

Apple's recommendation would be to charge and discharge your battery at least one time per month.  I wouldn't go below 20% discharge for the best battery life.  Apple also recommends that if you're storing your Macbook for an extended period of time, to charge it to only 50%, and powering it off afterward, for the best battery life.

https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/