# Li-Polymer laptop battery advice

Tags: laptop, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Battery Life Practice](https://superuser.com/questions/13024/battery-life-practice)  
>   [What is it that kills laptop batteries?](https://superuser.com/questions/77457/what-is-it-that-kills-laptop-batteries) 
>   [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

Hello, I've bought a new laptop - Dell Adamo. It has Lithium Polymer battery which is sealed (like in the MacBook Air), so I'm trying my best to extend it life.

- I've read somewhere that a typical battery have ~1000 recharge cycles. Does that mean full 100% to 0% cycles? Or just every time i plug the laptop is a "charge"?
- Is it bad for the battery if I work on the laptop and it charges (cause on the normal laptops I saw that it's better to remove it). Isn't that one of the 1000 cycles every time I work on it on plug?

Can someone, please explain me those things, cause I've searched a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- 1 charge cycle is typically a 0% to 100% full charge.
- actually most of the modern OSes (MacOS, Ubuntu, Win7) should stop charging the battery when it is full. so it shouldn't make any difference to your battery.

like for example on my Vista, I see this when the battery is full.

[image: Vista Charging]

Answer (score 1):

This Information was pulled from the HP website, but most of the information is relevant to all modern Notebook Lion batteries.

> Store Li-Ion batteries between 20°C and 25°C (68°F and 77°F) with 30% to 50% charge.
>
> Do not disassemble, crush, or puncture a battery; do not short the external contacts on a battery; and, do not dispose of a battery in fire or water.
>
> Do not leave batteries exposed to high temperatures for extended periods. Prolonged exposure to heat (for example, inside a hot car) will accelerate the deterioration of Li-Ion cells.
>
> Remove the battery if the notebook will be stored (turned off and not plugged into AC power) for more than 2 weeks.
>
> Remove the battery from the notebook if the notebook will be plugged into AC power continuously (via a wall adapter or docking station) for more than 2 weeks.
>
> Use the type of battery with the highest capacity (Ah) rating if the notebook will run high-end applications on battery power.
>
> Calibrate the battery based on the usage model. Under normal usage, batteries should be calibrated a minimum of once every 3 months; however, a battery that is rarely discharged fully should be calibrated about once a month

.

> Factors that contribute to loss of battery capacity
>
> Li-Ion battery cells suffer gradual, irreversible capacity loss with each discharge-charge cycle. Such aging occurs more rapidly as temperature and discharge loads increase.
>   The self-discharge rate of a Li-Ion battery is higher if the battery is left in an unpowered notebook.
>
> During prolonged storage or non-use, the battery charge will decrease below its recommended low-voltage level.
>
> Leaving the battery in a depleted condition for an extended period accelerates the decrease in full charge capacity.
>
> Leaving the battery at a high level of charge in a high-temperature environment for extended periods (for example, running a notebook computer in a docking station under a heavy load) also accelerates the loss of capacity.
>
> Running high-end applications using the battery accelerates the loss of capacity. For example, playing 3D games lowers full charge capacity faster than using word processing applications.

[Source of Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00596784&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN#c00596784_smart)

.

[Additional Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00596784&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4051838#c00596784_warranty)