# When to use laptop battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

When laptop battery is fully charged,  what is the best for battery life : use the battery or to use AC adapter (in general) and why ?

Answer (score 1):

Battery life is based on charge cycles (number of times charged/discharged) and temperature. If you've got an outlet and your battery is charged (or mostly-charged), remove the battery.

Comment: Is this still true?  I thought that removing the battery was only necessary on older batteries that would pick up a charge memory (i.e have no charge at all if run constantly on ac)?

Comment: I think it's more about the constant heat. Keeping the battery constantly charged & hot isn't good for the battery, so it helps to unplug it if you're just going to stay plugged into the wall. I spent a year with my laptop plugged into the wall with the battery in, and my battery life was really pitiful even with a low number of charge cycles compared to another laptop that I regularly removed the battery from when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an AC adapter all the time, the battery isn't charged or discharged at all, and because of that it's resource is not depleted. Battery's life only decreases when current flows through it, or, in the other words, if you charge or discharge it.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion:

If you can plug to AC, just do it and plug out your battery.

And just like any cellphone, if you start discharging your batteries go to the end of their power, in this way their live will be longer.

Batteries should be for where no grid is available.

In my opinion. ;)

Comment: Lithium batteries work differently. Deep discharging them is **bad**.

Comment: You don't have to. Laptops won't charge the battery if it's full.