# Laptop Battery Usage

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should laptops remain plugged in when their battery is 100% charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)
>   [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

I have a doubt regarding usage of power on a laptop

I have basically come across 2 widespread believes to maitain a healthy backup for battery :

1. Always keep the laptop on charge whenever on use ( If u have a power source nearby) and close it only when u shut it down
2. Charge it to 100%, remove the adapter, let it discharge to 10% and charge again.

So my question is which is the actual way to ensure a good health for battery for a long time ??

Answer (score 0):

How you charge your battery, and the temperature to which the battery gets exposed, are key factors that determine its lifespan.

1. **First Question**

   > 1. Always keep the laptop on charge whenever on use ( If u have a power source nearby) and close it only when u shut it down

   Most laptops nowadays use Li-ion batteries, and high temperatures are their worst enemy. If you keep the laptop always charging, you'll be getting an increasing concentration of heat, that with time will damage not only the battery but the laptop itself. It's not going to blow up, but its lifespan will diminish.

   On this subject, Jeff Atwood♦ [answer](https://superuser.com/a/205123/94664) to this question is quite enlightening:

   [Is it OK for the laptop to always be plugged in?](https://superuser.com/q/205118/94664)

   ---
2. **Second Question**

   > 2. Charge it to 100%, remove the adapter, let it discharge to 10% and charge again.

   Re-calibrate your battery every month or so by fully charging, fully discharging, and then fully charging again, is the best methodology yes. But you need to take into consideration that you should:

   - Refrain from using the laptop during the re-calibration process;
   - Turn off all power-saving features completely;
   - When discharging, let it get to the hibernation, not beyond that. When the laptop reaches 10% ~ 3% of energy capacity, hibernation kicks in and you know it's time to charge it up again.

   Reference: [HP Notebook PCs - Improving Battery Performance](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=3688868&prodTypeId=321957&objectID=c01297640)