# Should I use laptop while charging?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

Is it Okay to use laptop while charging? Does it have any bad effect on battery or laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the power supply can provide enough power for simultaneous normal operation and charging, there should be no issues.

Comment: Well I have mentioned in my answer I think it affects State Of Health of batteries if it is being charged all times.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Yea I come to realize that thanks for keeping me on track, but I thought it would be worthy mention here just to guide him.

Comment: :) girls use laptops too!

Answer (score 1):

Well usually it is suggested to keep the power of laptop unplugged when using battery, otherwise it affects the life of the battery. Direct power AC should only be provided to the laptop when the battery charge is approx 25-35% that is recommended. I've also seen people take out their batteries and use their laptops directly with AC power if there is no portability or power problems.

So it is not advised to keep the power plugged in all times, it destroys the battery and lifespan is affected inshort!

Comment: Two things reduce the battery discharging time, that is your battery's State of Health is affected. There was this one study:       1. Charging your battery when it is almost completely discharged 2. Charging the battery when it already full, so drill of taking out the battery and keeping the AC power I mentioned people do that.

Comment: Technically you are correct. Practically, there's no point. A laptop that I'll use over the next 4-5 years may see 20 minutes decrease in it's battery life after constant use with the power cord plugged in. However, the convenience factor and thought that once this actually happens I'll be purchasing a new battery or laptop begs the question whether it's work the convenience or not. I'd say keep it plugged in. If you notice the power adapter is getting too hot, you may want to take the latter option.

Comment: I saw many laptops loosing their batteries within a year or even less. Charging and using may be the real problem

Comment: The possible duplicate of this questions goes against your answer.

Comment: Do you have any references to support your unusual claim? Any laptop that continues charging the battery when it is full has a *faulty charging circuit*. Using this advice will wear out the battery *more quickly* than just leaving it on AC. Running off battery instead of AC when you have AC available will just put your laptop battery through more charge/discharge cycles than are necessary and this *will* age the battery.

Comment: @ Mark Booth I actually learned about this doing while doing a project on battery prognostics related material is here for your info http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/dash/pcoe/battery-prognostics/, actually we workrd on laptop batteries as test case

Comment: While an interesting site about profiling battery usage, none of the papers can be downloaded. Gathering data about battery behaviour and interpreting that data to make assertions about the best way to use batteries are two *very* different things. Do you have any publicly accessible evidence to support your assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a battery in all times smooths the power delivered to the computer, this can have a positive effect on the internal components.

Over the life of a laptop, you are likely to run in to other major faults before the battery gives up.

Comment: Well I might disagree, as their already an IC which manages the smoothing of power being delivered. One such IC from Compaq CQ61 laptop is TPS 51125 IC which does the same job as protection against fluctuations in voltage.