# Does the battery last longer if you unplug it when on power?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use a laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

Is this true (For Dell laptops) ?

Comment: I suggest you read this to learn the facts about notebook batteries, this info applies to Dell batteries also, all modern notebook batteries are the same technology...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know the answer is **yes**, it's always  good to unplug battery when your laptop  has power cable attached on it

Comment: AFAIK on modern laptops the current flow to the battery is cut when battery is charged. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the electrical system you're connected with generally experiences power outages and voltage waving problems, it's not a good idea to remove the battery.

Comment: Draining the battery to 30-40% before removal is optimum for storing the battery for 2 weeks or more. Removing the battery when on AC does not help the battery live longer unless you plan on using it on "AC only" for 2 weeks or longer.

Answer (score 3):

Two separate issues:

You can *remove* the battery when the laptop is *plugged* into AC, so that the battery does not charge, but this is generally not recommended. Some systems won't operate at full speed when there is no battery. Some might not work at all. And imagine if the power goes out; you should have a built-in backup battery, but instead the computer dies.

If you almost always have AC, you should still occasionally *unplug* on occasion, even when it is on. The idea that you must "move electrons through" the battery to exercise it. If it is constantly topped off, the battery will lose its ability to hold a charge.